# how to fetch image  from array and show it on table view

Tags: iphone, arrays

I am fetching image from server and save it on a `NSMutableArray`. The result of array like that

```
myarray={"roger_50.jpg",....};
```

Now i dont know how to access this image on table view.

Comment: what u have in array image name or image data plz explain

Comment: are you asking how can you access to your array by touching a row in a tableView ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just have proper URL for image in array. And pass it to NSURL object as a link.

```
 NSURL *imageURL = [NSURL URLWithString:[myarray objectAtIndex : yourindex]];  
 NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:imageURL];  
 UIImage *image = [[UIImage alloc] initWithData:data];
```

Have a nice coding.
Stay Hungry, Stay Foolish...

Answer (score 0):

i hope the thing you are getting from array are only the names you can retrieve images from server in only two ways i) in nsdata ii)by url of the images on sever .By this way you cann't access the images.

Comment: i think he have url in array.

Comment: @Ron- i think so he have just a name of images .. :)

Comment: @Ballu--My problem is still remain...but thanks for helping...i will try to fetch the url of image rather than image name

Comment: Ask your server guy to provide the url of the images you can display them easily then.

Comment: @Ballu--i fetch image url in array.
   myarray={"http://www.abc.com/uploads/sarab.jpg",....}

Comment: Now you just have to add this                                   NSData *Data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:url]];
UIImage *image = [[UIImage alloc] initWithData:Data cache:NO];
uiimageview.image = image;